# How to return iteratively updated data frame from function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, while-loop, return-value

Say I want to perform iterative calculations inside a while loop and maintain a running record, then return the dataset as follows (using proper scoping):

```
df <- data.frame(iter=integer(), x=integer())
x = 0

df_func <- function(df, x, num_iter){
  i = 0
  while(i < num_iter){
    i = i + 1
    x = x + 10
    new_df = data.frame(iter=i, x=x)
    df <<- rbind(df, new_df)
  }
  return(df)
}

df_func(df, x, 10)
```

I'd like `df` to contain ten rows with x=1 to 10 values, but instead I get only the last row:

```
> df
  iter   x
1   10 100
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use `<<-` if you are doing to return the value from the function. Just use `df <- rbind(df, new_df)` and then `df <- df_func(df, x, 10)`. Functions should not manipulate variables outside their scope.

Comment: Also check out Circle 2 in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Growing objects in a loop with rbind is very inefficient. Better ways exist.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you again! The R Inferno is a handy reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To somewhat expand on MrFlick's comments:

The issue here is that functions in R perform pass-by-value: `df` *inside* `df_func` is a copy of `df` (the `data.frame` with empty columns `iter` and `x`) passed to the function. This copy is never modified due to the usage of `<<-`. Instead, in each iteration of `while`

`df <<- rbind(df, new_df)`,

which is equivalent to

`df <<- rbind(data.frame(iter=integer(), x=integer()), new_df)`,

modifies `df` in the global environment, resulting in

```
> df
  iter   x
1   10 100
```

after 10 iterations.